# Maven doesn't put downloaded jars in eclipse's JRE System Library "folder"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created project using this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} -DartifactId={project-name} -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

After downloading libraries my project looks like this:
http://i43.tinypic.com/2iut1me.jpg

How can I "tell" maven to download jars in just one folder?

Comment: I don't think this is a issue with maven. This is the way eclipse displays all your referenced libraries.

Comment: Could be, though I can't find a way to group downloaded jars.
Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Maven will not download jars in a single folder, instead, it create a dir structure in a $HOME/.m2/repository for managing your dependencies, including versions.

If you want the jars to show in the Eclipse project, create a pom.xml file in your project with the correct dependencies, for example

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<groupId>com.myGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
<name>myProjectName</name>
<version>myProjectVersion</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dependency1</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency1</artifactId>
            <version>dependency1</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dependency2</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency2</artifactId>
            <version>dependency2</version>
        </dependency>   
        <!-- .... and so on -->
</dependencies>
```

Also, configure your project in eclipse to be a Maven project and then you will see "Maven Dependencies"in your project.

Comment: Have you seen screenshot of my project?
Project already has pom.xml, and I have downloaded all jars I wanted.

Comment: Please note the little 'M' that is displayed on the left top corner of the project folder, indicating that is a Maven project and also, notice the 'Maven Dependencies' Folder that is created there. Once maven is enabled, it should manage all the jars for you, so you don't have to download them yourself, as it will check in build time what are the jars you have and what you're missing. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2cg1ldd&s=5#.Uo6eYaUVy7c